# WCF DataMember List<> without enclosing element

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontract

The following DataContract:

```
    [DataContract(Namespace = "http://namespace", Name = "Blarg")]
    public class Blarg
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Attribute")]
        public string Attribute{ get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "Record", IsRequired = false, Order = 4)]
        public List<Record> Record{ get; set; }
    }
```

Serializes into this:

```
<Blarg Attribute="blah">
    <Record>
        <Record/>
        <Record/>
        <Record/>
    </Record>
</Blarg>
```

But I want this:

```
<Blarg>
    <Record/>
    <Record/>
    <Record/>
<Blarg/>
```

The DataContractSerializer seems to be inserting the header parent  automagically and I don't want it.

How do I go about removing the wrapping `<Record>`?

Comment: Why are you using "`XmlAttribute`"? the Data Contract Serializer never uses attributes.

Comment: The XmlAttribute Serializes without any issues throguh the DataContract Serilaizer - bu that not the issue I am having.

Comment: it doesn't serialize as an attribute, though, which is what it's `XmlAttribute` is intended for. I recommend you remove it and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do that.

The `DataContractSerializer` is optimized for speed, and in the process it sacrifices some flexibility and some features (like XML attributes). I don't think you have much chance to influence the DCS - it does its job as it sees fit, and as quickly as possible. You get to define quite neatly *what* to serialize (with the `[DataMember]` attribute, but you don't really have a say in *how* to serialize.

If you need more control, you could pick the `XmlSerializer` instead - in that case, you have 10-15% slower serialization, but you can control things like the shape of the data etc. But even in this case - I am not aware of any way you can tell the XML serializer to serialize a collection into a series of XML tags without an enclosing tag for the collection.

Comment: I switched to XmlSerializer and was able to remove the enclosing tag. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Ryan: care to share **how** you did this?? You can answer your own question with that solution - would be useful to someone, someday, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591045/data-contract-serializer-how-to-omit-the-outer-element-of-a-collection). 
See the short story bellow(for the long one checkout the url):

```
 [XmlElement ("Parameter")]
    public List<Parameter> Parameters;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent a `DataContract` object to serialize the items of a collection property inside a wrapper element. However, you can produce the desired XML by creating a class that implements `IXmlSerializable` and the `WriteXml` method. Here's the code for the example you provided:

```
public class Blarg : IXmlSerializable
{
    public string Attribute { get; set; }

    public List<Record> Records { get; set; }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement(nameof(Blarg), "http://namespace");
        writer.WriteAttributeString(nameof(Attribute), Attribute);
        DataContractSerializer recordSerializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Record));

        foreach (Record rec in Records)
        {
            recordSerializer.WriteObject(writer, rec);
        }

        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
}
```

Even though `Blarg` is not a `DataContract` class, it can contain object properties of `DataContract` classes, such as `Record`, so that they can be serialized within `WriteXml` using a `DataContractSerializer` instance. In case you need a property that also implements `IXmlSerializable`, you would need to serialize it by calling its own `WriteXml` method inside the `WriteXml` of the containing class.