# WCF error: Expecting state 'Element'.. Encountered 'Text' with name '', namespace '' post call in XML format

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xmlserializer, datacontractserializer

I have a WCF service method that can't deserialize the post in XML format and will error with

> Error in line 14 position 30. Expecting state 'Element'.. Encountered
> 'Text' with name '', namespace ''

I narrow down to the specific section like the reproducible sample below

```
var xmlSrc = @"<Keys>
                  <ProductKeyID>123</ProductKeyID>
                  <ProductKeyID>124</ProductKeyID>
                  <ProductKeyID>125</ProductKeyID>
               </Keys>";
DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Keys));
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlSrc)))
{

    var i = (Keys)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
}

[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
[Serializable]
public class Keys
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public List<string> ProductKeyID { get; set; }
}
```

How to adjust the C# class to deserialize the XML properly?

I do search the post exists but most of them are json format and do not seem to help my case.

Comment: Related or duplicate: [Data Contract Serializer - How to omit the outer element of a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8591045/3744182).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative you can use `CollectionDataContract` attribute. Your class `Keys` will be inherited from `List`. In `CollectionDataContract` attribute specify name of the root element and name of items.

```
[CollectionDataContract(Name = "Keys", ItemName = "ProductKeyID", Namespace ="")]
public class Keys<T> : List<T>
{
}

DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Keys<string>));
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlSrc)))
{
    var i = (Keys<string>)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
}
```