# WCF [DataContract] use List<>

Tags: list, wcf, datacontract

WCF DataMember `List<>` without enclosing element

The following `DataContract`:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://namespace", Name = "Blarg")]
public class Blarg
{
    [XmlAttribute("Attribute")]
    public string Attribute{ get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<Record> Records{ get; set; }
}
```

Serializes into this:

```
<Blarg Attribute="blah">
    <Records>
        <Record/>
        <Record/>
        <Record/>
    </Records>
</Blarg>
```

But I would like this:

```
 <Blarg>
    <Record/>
    <Record/>
    <Record/>
 <Blarg/>
```

Comment: have you tried "public class Blarg : List<Record>"  ?

Comment: Please, Could you show me the example code

Comment: I can't believe this, but its here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267709/wcf-datamember-list-without-enclosing-element

Comment: thank you very much for your help